# multiple select form two-way binding

Tags: json, angular, forms, angular-material, two-way-binding

I have a multiple select form:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

    <mat-select  [(value)]="selected"  multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping">{{topping.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

I want to display options that user selected under the form with `<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>`, but if I do it this way I get when I select 3 toppings:

```
   You Selected: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Now I tried `<p>You selected: {{selected?.value}}</p>` I don't get any entry.

The only solution I have found so far is:
 `<p>You selected: {{selected | json}}</p>` but I do not want whole json object just value property.

How do I get it to display:

```
You selected: option1, option2, option3
```

?

Comment: Whenever you see [object, object] it's due to a key value pair. This usually means you have an array of objects. To see the values use a span with ngfor and display item.value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing "[object, object]" means you are trying to use an object as a string.

`toppings` is an array of objects. You are looping through this array with `let topping of toppings` and assigning an object to `topping`.

`{{topping.value}}` prints the string in the `.value` property of topping object but you assigned back the whole object in `[value]="topping"`.

This way `selected` becomes an array of objects although you are only seeing strings while clicking on options.

Two ways to achieve what you want;

**- Pass string from options**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

    <mat-select  [(value)]="selected"  multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping.value">{{topping.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

**- Loop through selected array**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

    <mat-select  [(value)]="selected"  multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping">{{topping.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
<p>You selected: 
    <span *ngFor="let s of selected; let f = first; let l = last;">
        {{s.value}}
        <span *ngIf="!(f && l) && !l">,</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

I hope this helps you clarify angular templating and data binding.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try Changing your HTML to :- 

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

    <mat-select  [(value)]="selected"  multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping">{{topping.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
<p>You selected: {{selected | json}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a new property on the component to bind in the template, or make a new pipe to display comma-delimited items.

Without a pipe:

```js
get displaySelections(): string {
  return this.selections.map(s => s.value).join(', ');
}
```

```html
<p>You selected: {{displaySelections}}</p>
```

With a pipe, you can re-use in other components as well, and you don't need to add the getter:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'join'
})
export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: {value: any}[]): string {
    return value.map(v => v.value).join(', ');
  }
}
```

```html
<p>You selected: {{ selections | join }}</p>
```